# Immersions of quasi-compact quasi-separated schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, compactness

Let $f : X \to Y$ be an immersion of quasi-compact schemes. Hence we may write $f$ as a closed immersion $g : X \to U$  followed by an open immersion $h : U \to Y$.

**Question.** Is $U$ quasi-compact? If not, can we choose a factorization $f = h \circ g$ such that $U$ is quasi-compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a proof that $U$ can be chosen to be quasi-compact, and it is quite easy.

Let $U = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ be an open affine covering. Then $X=\bigcup_{i \in I} g^{-1}(U_i)$ is an open affine covering. Since $X$ is quasi-compact, we get $X = \bigcup_{i \in E} g^{-1}(U_i)$ for a finite subset $E \subseteq I$. Since closed immersions are stable under base change, it follows that $g' : X \to \bigcup_{i \in E} U_i$ is a closed immersion. We also have the open immersion $h' : \bigcup_{i \in E} U_i \to \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i \to Y$ and $f = h' \circ g'$.